# insert a string at a specific position

Tags: javascript, regex

i have an array and i want to insert **"ZZ"** if the current array value(string) contains **"ata"**, the code should replace at the end of **"ata"** word.

```js
var duplicatesArray = ["abıca","abrık","apşak","abbak","abu","aparma","apalisına","appak","aparmadutı","apşak","apışık","apşak","apışıklık","apışık","apalak","apılamak","apul","apul","apulamak","aparmak","at","arkasına","gelmek","ata","atabeg","at","eri","at","ağaç","at","oğlanı","at","akdarıcı","at","otayıcı","at","uşağı","at","oğlanı","at","oynağı","at","bırakmak","at","boynuna","düşmek","at","boynuna","düşmek","at","cıvlandurmak","at","çapmak","at","çapmak","at","depretmek","at","depmek","atı","doldurmak","at","segirtmek","ateş","evi","ateş","göyniigi","atışmak","ateşe","urmak","ateşe","nal","komak","at","şalmak","at","şalmak","at","tonı","at","kaşnısı","at","kaldırmak","at","kulağı","at","koparmals","at","koşmak","at","kulağı","götliği","atlaz","atlandurmak","atlandurmak","atlanmak","atlu","azuğı","atımı","yir","ata","atalar","atıcıduğı","aç","itmek","acıtğan","acıtmak","aç","dirilmek","acır","acırak","acışıklık","acışmak","aç","tutmak"
];

var uniqueArray = duplicatesArray.filter(function(elem, pos) {
  return duplicatesArray.indexOf(elem) == pos;
});
 


for (var i = 0; i < uniqueArray.length; i++) {
  var st = uniqueArray[i];
  if((st.endsWith("mak")==false) && (st.endsWith("mek")== false) && (st.length>3))
  {
   
    var b = "ata";
    var insert = "ZZ";
    
    var position = st.indexOf("b");
   st = st.slice(0, position) + insert + st.slice(position);
  
  
    document.writeln(st);
    document.write("<br>");
    
    
  }
  

  }
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong in your current version? Could you give an example of the desired output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: how can i edit it ? there is no modification button ...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may need to edit this answer later once some details have been clarified, but it seems like you should use the `.map()` method on your `uniqueArray`.

This code will walk through each word in the list and either let it unchanged or apply the replacement if all conditions are fulfilled.

```js
// using a shorter, already deduplicated list for sake of clarity
var uniqueArray = [
  "abıca","gelmek","ata","atabeg","at","eri","yir","atalar","tutmak"
];

var result = uniqueArray.map(function(word) {
  return (
    !word.endsWith("mak") &&
    !word.endsWith("mek") &&
    word.length > 3 ?
    word.replace(/ata/, "ataZZ") : word
  );
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am right or wrong? :)

```
var initialArray = ["abıca","abrık","apşak","abbak","abu","aparma","apalisına","appak","aparmadutı","apşak","apışık","apşak","apışıklık","apışık","apalak","apılamak","apul","apul","apulamak","aparmak","at","arkasına","gelmek","ata","atabeg","at","eri","at","ağaç","at","oğlanı","at","akdarıcı","at","otayıcı","at","uşağı","at","oğlanı","at","oynağı","at","bırakmak","at","boynuna","düşmek","at","boynuna","düşmek","at","cıvlandurmak","at","çapmak","at","çapmak","at","depretmek","at","depmek","atı","doldurmak","at","segirtmek","ateş","evi","ateş","göyniigi","atışmak","ateşe","urmak","ateşe","nal","komak","at","şalmak","at","şalmak","at","tonı","at","kaşnısı","at","kaldırmak","at","kulağı","at","koparmals","at","koşmak","at","kulağı","götliği","atlaz","atlandurmak","atlandurmak","atlanmak","atlu","azuğı","atımı","yir","ata","atalar","atıcıduğı","aç","itmek","acıtğan","acıtmak","aç","dirilmek","acır","acırak","acışıklık","acışmak","aç","tutmak"];
var newArray = []
var regexp = /(ata)(.*)?/;
for (var i = 0; i< initialArray.length; i += 1) {
  newArray.push(initialArray[i].replace(regexp, "$1ZZ$2"))
}
console.log(newArray)
// ... "gelmek", "ataZZ", "ataZZbeg" ...
```

Comment: What is the point of matching arbitrary characters after the `"ata"` and then immediately putting them back with `$2`?

Comment: @torazaburo In array we had "ata" and " ata.* "strings.
Maybe I had wrong answer a bit